# How to read image names from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having multidimensional array and In multidimensional array I am getting image/banner names with single image and images with comma seprated.

Now I want to display all image/baneer in silder so with this multidimensional array, how it will be possible with loop?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [banners] => http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 143038313801.jpg,143038313809.jpg,143038313811.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [banners] => 143038306301.jpg,143038306302.jpg,143038306303.jpeg,143038306310.jpg,143038306311.jpg,143038306312.png
        )

)
```

I want to use all bellow image names in slider.

```
http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg
143038313801.jpg
143038313809.jpg
143038313811.jpg
143038306301.jpg
143038306302.jpg
143038306303.jpeg
143038306310.jpg
143038306311.jpg
143038306312.png
```

Any idea?

I have never done this way so no I idea how to do that so need your support.

```
What I have done:

for($i=0; $i<count($getBefamousHomepage); $i++){
    echo $getBefamousHomepage[$i]['banners'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something? (research, code, pseudo code) Show your work/effort/attempts!

Comment: Yes I am trying but it very initial stage.

Comment: Doesn't matter, just show what you already have!

Comment: I have created basic loop but stuck when image/banner are with commas and dont know how to conitnue with this loop.

Comment: So where are we now with the question?

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for your support. I have tried `Albert Kozłowski` code It is working perfect for me.

Comment: okay; (just curious, so did my code not worked?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with your example:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($getBefamousHomepage); $i++) {
    foreach (explode(',',$getBefamousHomepage[$i]['banners']) as $banner) {
        echo $banner;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

Just go through your array with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), then simply [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) all values by a comma and print it [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'ed, like this:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v){
    echo implode("<br>", explode(",", $v));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$given_multi_array; // Store your result into this array
$image_names = array(); // To store image names.
```

//loop given array $given_multi_array and store to $image_names

```
foreach($given_multi_array as $key => $val)
{
foreach($val as $key1 => $image_name)
{
 $image_names =  $image_name;
}
}
 print_r($image_names);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is inappropriate when you are not dealing with variable-depth data.  In this case, you know exactly how much depth you are working with.  In fact, you know you specifically want to target a single column of data.  PHP has a dedicated function to call for this: `array_column()`.

Here is a clean, direct function-based process with no unnecessary overhead:

1. isolate the columnar data.
2. join all elements with the same delimiter used within the elements (comma).
3. replace all commas with a `<br>` tag.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mPSr3))

```
$array = [
    ['banners' => 'http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg'],
    ['banners' => '143038313801.jpg,143038313809.jpg,143038313811.jpg'],
    ['banners' => '143038306301.jpg,143038306302.jpg,143038306303.jpeg,143038306310.jpg,143038306311.jpg,143038306312.png']
];

echo str_replace(",", "<br>", implode(",", array_column($array, 'banners')));
```

Output:

```
http://www.eclipse-pos.com/eclipse/images/small_banner2.jpg
143038313801.jpg
143038313809.jpg
143038313811.jpg
143038306301.jpg
143038306302.jpg
143038306303.jpeg
143038306310.jpg
143038306311.jpg
143038306312.png
```